# How do I get the current subvolid of a mounted btrfs?

Tags: btrfs

How do you get the top level subvolid of a mounted btrfs?  I want the actual subvolid that is mounted at this moment and not the default subvolid (which could be different.)

Answer (score 0):

Look at `/proc/mounts` or the output of `mount`, the subvolid is always listed in the mount options.

```
/dev/loop0 /mnt/btrfs btrfs rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/ 0 0
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```